# If a US citizen didn't realize that they overstayed in the UK and then found out, what are they expected to do?

Tags: uk, us-citizens, overstaying, visa-free-entry

Are you expected to leave immediately if you have already been existing in the country for a few years? Do you have some time allowance for when you're expected to make your way out? If you realize that you've overstayed and would like to do the right thing, what is the time frame that you're expected to act in?

I am in the UK.

Comment: How could you not realise you are overstaying by several years? A few days, maybe but not years

Comment: If you didn't realize that it was time limited and had been misinformed of the rules, or gotten sucked into a whirlwind of life and had it slip your mind, or some combination of both...

Comment: https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/immigration/stay-in-uk/overstayed-visa/ may partially answer the question.

Comment: Ignorance of the law is not a valid defence.  In your case, you overstayed by years after entering the UK via an unlawful means after a visa rejection - thats not “forgetting”, that would be seen as wilful.

Comment: I agree you should leave as soon as possible but before leaving you need to wrap up your life in the UK on the assumption you will not be back there for years, if ever. For example, sell any property you do not plan to take with you. See [UK visa refusal, seeking temporary entry to collect personal items](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76471/19560) for some problems due to leaving without doing so, and then being denied entry.

Comment: There's a lot of useful context in [this related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/157703) from the OP

Comment: @Joseph P. How does it ‘slip your mind’ that you’re living in a country where you have no right to live? You have overstayed way over any theoretical grace period. Take Patricia Shanahan’s advice: wrap up your life in the UK and leave ASAP, before you come to the attention of UK Immigration authorities.

Comment: Maybe also contact a reputable lawyer specialized in this kind of immigration problems. (If there are any.)

Comment: They aren't going to believe you didn't know about the time limitation, because [they stamped it right into your passport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTchB.jpg).

Comment: @MichaelHampton in this case, the OP entered the UK via Ireland using the Common Travel Area route to Scotland and a US passport *card*.  And then overstayed by three years.

Comment: @JosephP., The first rule here is 'be it nice'. Insulting people is not acceptable. The person you are insulting is stating the facts you gave in other posts so everybody can help you better.

Comment: I can't even see what I wrote anymore, so I'm guessing it got removed. But I would have argued that the unhelpful attitudes towards me have not been "nice."

Answer (score 10):

You were refused entry and had your passport stamped accordingly. You then entered Britain via Ireland, without encountering UK immigration. Immediately, your status is suspect, but after three years there is no question: you are in Britain illegally. There is no way you could not have known this, and nobody in the UK authorities will believe it is a mistake.

If you come to the attention of UK Immigration now they'll probably have you on a plane so fast your feet won't touch the ground. Alternatively, they'll put you in an immigration detention centre until they can put you on a plane. That's not an experience you will enjoy.

You should, therefore, arrange to leave the UK as soon as possible. Since your departure will be notified to UK Immigration by the airline you can assume that your illegal presence will be on record and you will find it difficult, if not impossible, to return. You should arrange your affairs in the UK accordingly.

<sup>(Thanks to various contributors whose comments were used to compile this answer)</sup>

Comment: This pretty much echoes my answer on https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157703/what-is-the-best-way-to-maximize-chances-of-reentry-upon-leaving-the-uk - I am not complaining, because its obvious that the OP is not getting the picture and needs to be told it time and again, so upvote for this answer!  The OP needs to understand that they are an illegal immigrant and will be dealt with as such.

Comment: If they went back from Ireland via the Common Travel Area, would it still be reported to immigration?

Comment: @Obie2.0 yes, and Ireland would be upset as well, as they’ve overstayed their Irish entry conditions.

Comment: Thank you Obie for being creative. Moo you have not cited anything to support that, and the home office official materials state that only air travel has 100% API collection coverage. Other journeys are closer to 80%. You should cite a reference if you want to be so stuck up and nihilist.

Comment: Thank you Arthur's pass for your at least somewhat useful/informative answer. Actually I found out from a solicitor that self financed departure would result in a 1 year ban. Ho-financed voluntary departure would result in a 2 year ban. Forced removal would result in 10 years. The rules are deterministic and clear and it doesn't appear that a permanent ban is on the table.

Comment: @josephP Don't confuse a ban (where a visa application or entry to the UK is automatically refused without being considered) with refusals. You have shown yourself to be willing to flout the rules. You will have to work much harder now to overcome the suspicion that you will do so again.

Comment: Yes but I have been led to believe that according to the rules, if you overstay by more than either 1 or 3 months (I can't remember which), then you are almost sure to be banned for between 1 and 10 years. If you leave voluntarily then 1 if at own expense or 2 if at hmg's expense. If you are removed forcibly then banned for 10 years.

Comment: @Joseph P. To add to the comment by Arthur’s Pass about bans vs refusals, one of the grounds for discretionary refusal of entry is “contriving to frustrate the Immigration Rules” https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673999/GGFR-Section-2-v29.0EXT.PDF#page53 You entered the UK via Ireland after being denied entry. That sounds very much like ‘contriving’ to me.

Comment: This is all quite relevant and useful. Thank you traveler.

Comment: @JosephP. "it doesn't appear that a permanent ban is on the table." even if you get a 1 year ban or no ban at all, why do you think British authorities will be trying their hardest to approve you a visa or let you in using the visa-free scheme with your history (refusal of entry + unlawful entry to the UK + overstay for years)? In my honest opinion, you will probably never be granted a visa for the UK or Ireland, and definitely won't be let in through the visa-free scheme. It's not a permanent ban, but if you will never be able to come back in your lifetime, what is the difference anyway?

Comment: Thanks for explaining this kiradotee. I value your honest opinion. May I just ask what it is drawn from though? From whence arises your familiarity with the ukvi system's workings?

Comment: But I had reentered in genuine good faith upon the advice of not one, not two British embassies.

Comment: @josephp So why didn't you leave in good faith before your six months were up?

Comment: That is a separate question, not related as you suggest to the previous one. I entered in good faith but stayed due to complex extenuating circumstances.

Comment: @JosephP You asked a question here and got an answer. If you think there's some nuanced excuse for being in Britain illegally then get in touch with UK Immigration and see how they react.

Comment: You were there one who pressed me on both of those two things not being able to simultaneously hold true. It seems ridiculous to question me on the first point of good faith entry (on both your collective part here with the skeptical attitude here which many have expressed, and on the part of UKVI) when I was, honest to God, advised by both the American and the Irish UK embassies to simply reattempt entry, which I did. They also referred me to a British law firm in NYC that told me the same, that I didn't need a visa, but that if for some silly irrational reason I would want to pay their

Comment: Rather dauntingly exorbitant hourly consultation rate they could help me apply for entry clearance although it they were adamant that it wasn't necessary.